# Awk command to get search records with number of occurence of search pattern

Tags: file, search, awk

```
 awk 'FNR==NR { ! a[$0]++ ; next }
      { b[$0]++ }
      END {
            for (i in a) {
                for (k in b) {
                    if (a[i]==1 && i ~ k ) { print i }
                }
            }
      }' file1 file2
```

The above awk script program helped me out to get the search criteria from one file and accordingly to that search pattern i am able to get the record from other file. But from this script it is taking unique search record, if the same content is exist twice in file than also it search and print only once. I want the repeated record also to get the count of occurence of that record in the file.

Comment: Some sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I gather that the array 'a' is storing all the records and array 'b' is storing all the regular expression search patterns.

Just change your if statement to:

```
if ( i ~ k ) { print i, a[i] } #a[i] prints the count of the record
```

Comment: Not exactly, `! a[$0]++` means it is only storing unique values and not duplicate values.